# how to delete sms using alarm manager

Tags: android, sms, alarmmanager

I would like create an app that can clear received sms, which are older than certain amount of time. What I do not know is that, what value should I use to trigger that alarm manager and how to update the alarm manager, so that it can delete the next message. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can follow these steps:

Step 1: Start a service Register broadcast receiver for receiving the event of certain time everyday. (Like alarm that would go off on 9 AM everyday)

Step 2: You can check for old SMS in onReceive() of your receiver.

Step 3: Delete those SMS which are older than certain timelimit.

So, it will run everyday to delete old SMS.